# How to prevent "No route matches ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a view that adds an item to a shopping cart with a line

```
=button_to "To cart", :action => 'add_to_cart', :id => product
```

Because button_to use post, when a user requests `/store/add_to_cart/wouldBeArticleButNot`
I get a

```
`"Routing Error  No route matches [GET] "/store/add_to_cart/wouldBeArticleButNot"`
```

with lots of routes.
How can I prevent this type of messages about routes not supported?
I know I could had used link_to that uses GET but I´m more interested on handling this kind of cases in `routes.rb`

Could anybody help me?

Comment: How does your routing for `/store/add_to_cart/wouldBeArticleButNot` look like. Please post the relevant parts of your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

Please set up your route in `route.rb` to make `add_to_cart` a POST request.

Comment: Maybe didnt explain well. The program works as intended. "button_to" uses POST and in routes.rb I have a ´post "store/add_to_cart/:id" => 'store#add_to_cart'´ line for this. What I want to prevent are routing error messages when somebody intendes to break the system. For example if one of my routes is /store/new(.:format) -as appears in rake routes- and the cracker requests "/store/new/2", Rails would show a long "Routing error.." and don´t want those messages for security reasons.